# Combobox automatically dropdown

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox

I have editable combobox, MVVM.
I need dropdown=true when I write something in combobox.

```
 Text="{Binding textsearch, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

here in **textsearch** I wrote OnPropertyChange for ComboBox IsDropDownOpen=true, but it works only onсe, when I select row, then try to write again, the dropdown=false  and not react to property...

Also, when I selected row and change text, I can't select this row again, because it was selected, I need change selected item first, but when I change selected Item, the text changes too.

How to make filter works?

Or like another variant, I added textbox for filter text, but when I write text and call **textsearch** property, the textbox lost focus and combobox has this focus... how to save focus on textbox and dropdown combobox itemslist?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do something like that is to handle one or more events. You could try to handle the [`PreviewTextInput` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput.aspx):

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" IsEditable="True" 
    PreviewTextInput="ComboBox_PreviewTextInput" />
```

...

```
private void ComboBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
    comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
}
```

The code in this event handler will open the drop down each time a user types into the `ComboBox TextBox`. You may need to handle a few more events to get your exact desired behaviour, but you can see which events are available from the [ComboBox Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox_events%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN and complete this yourself.